# key distribution is not correct in bull redis cluster

Tags: node.js, redis, bull, bullmq

I have around 16 queues, which are being used for delayed jobs.
Some queues are used multiple times, In a one-time slot, there are some queues which are being used around 50 times and the rest are 3 to 4 times.

Implementation examples:-

```
import Bull from 'bull';

const queue1 = new Bull('queue1', {
  prefix: '{1}'
});

....

const queue16 = new Bull('queue16', {
  prefix: '{16}'
});
```

I am using redis-lab as a scheduler,
Have a look at key distribution per shard
[image: CPU usage per shard]

Any solution how can I improve the above graph